# OpenID Connect (owin) - multiple providers - select provider through querystring

Tags: openid-connect

We have a site `A` that uses an openid connect application that offers multiple providers (ADFS, Google, Facebook) for logging in. This works fine. 
What we would like is to make three buttons on the site `A` to directly connect (through redirects to the api) to the selected provider.
In ADFS you can supply a parameter (`whr`) to automatically redirect to the desired provider. Is there something similar in openid connect? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Good question actually - an idp parameter is commonly used as the equivalent of whr - Ping Federate uses idp.

I don't think it is mentioned in standards though - so it may vary between vendors.